# Topology Exercise 5.9 Manetti (Quotient topology)

Tags: general-topology

I’m having difficulties proving a simple exercise about quotient topology from Manetti’s book.

Exercise 5.9 Prove that $[0,1]/A$ where $A$ is a set containing two distinct points of $[0,1]$ has 3 different classes of homeomorphism as $A$ varies.

What I tried:

I showed that if $A=\{0,1\}$ then $[0,1]/A$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

I tried to find an explicit homeomorphism for the other 2 cases (that I think lead to different homeomorphism) which are given by the contraction of $A=\{0,x\}$ with $0<x<1$ and $A=\{x,y\}$ with $0<x<y<1$ with no luck.

So I tried to prove that the 3 different quotient spaces are not homeomorphic.
I observed that if I consider the quotient given by the contraction of $A=\{0,x\}$ and remove $[x]$ it is not connected while $S^1$ without a point is always connected, I’m not sure if this is a valid solution.

For the last space with $A=\{x,y\}$ I followed the same principle and removed the point $[x]$ which should lead to a similar result.
I did not prove it is not homeomorphic to the second space though.

I feel like I’m approaching this in the wrong way but I just started studying the quotient topology chapter and I would love some tips on how to reason about this before moving to other exercises.

this is the first time I post here, if you have any note on the question feel free to share it, I hope I decently exposed my questions.

Comment: If you are satisfied with a visual approach you could just say that if you remove the central point from $I/\{x, y\}$ you find a space with three components, while if you remove a point from $I/\{0, x\}$ you find a space with either one or two components.

Comment: You have a circle, a circle with a tail and a circle with two tails. The circle can have a point removed and still stay connected and the other two can have a point removed that breaks it into two and three connected components, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is absolutely correct. I suggest to formalize it as follows.

1. For $x,y \in I = [0,1]$ with $x < y$ define $I_{x,y} = I/\{x,y\}$.
2. Show that each $I_{x,y}$ is homeomorphic to one of $I_{0,1}, I_{0,\frac 1 2}$ and $I_{\frac 1 3,\frac 23}$.
3. You have already shown that $I_{0,1}$ and $I_{0,\frac 1 2}$ are not homeomorphic.
4. Remove the point given as the equivalence class of the set $\{\frac 1 3,\frac 2 3 \}$ from $I_{\frac 1 3,\frac 2 3}$. This leaves a space having three connected components. Removal of any point from $I_{0,1}$ gives a space  with one connected component, removal of any point from $I_{0,\frac 1 2}$ gives a space with one or two components. This shows that $I_{\frac 1 3,\frac 2 3}$ cannot be homeomorphic to $I_{0,1}$ or to $I_{0,\frac 1 2}$.

Comment: In your example is $I_{\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}}$ actually $I_{\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}}$?

Comment: @Adriano Yes, it was a typo (copy and paste ...).

Comment: Thank you, I find your explanation clear